# How good is the Telligent Evolution Platform SharePoint integration?

Tags: third-party-software, integration

How good is the integration of the Telligent Evolution Platform in SharePoint? I need some reviews.

Comment: @sankaranD: Please take when asking questions. Capital letters look like you are shouting. Thanks! I've edited both your questions to give you a better idea of what we're looking for.

Comment: @sankaranD: Also I've set this particular question to 'community wiki' as it doesn't have a precise answer and rather asks for opinions. See http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean

Comment: Does anbody object if we close this question? Per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial, third-party products. Answers are probably out of date also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that Telligent Evolution Platform is similiar in purpose to WSS / SharePoint Foundation - in that they're both an software system for data storage and presentation (Gooing by Community Server which is written on top of Evolution Platform).

It depends what you need from Telligent that you want integrating in SharePoint - if you want data stored in Telligent to be surfaced in SharePoint then this can be done with BCS.

Telligent runs on ASP.NET, so any ASP.NET Web Parts written in managed code for SharePoint may be able to run in Telligent (with many exceptions of course, for considerations like CAS, Object Model access, etc).

Do you have a current environment build on Telligent Evolution that you want to surface in SharePoint or do you plan to migrate the environment over to SharePoint?

Comment: Can you share Telligent link where the details of such integration is described? We are specifically looking and utilizing Share point doc lib feature within Telligent (probably a s a widget). If you can provide more information on this direction I it will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Alex, like James mentioned above, there are several different *integration* methods between Telligent Evolution and Microsoft SharePoint.  Telligent can provide integration with Microsoft SharePoint through its platform. The Telligent Evolution platform provides a web services API (REST-based) allowing organizations to integrate with any open application, including Microsoft SharePoint and other document management systems. Due to the unique needs of each organization, it does require some integration work.

With Telligent Evolution 2.5, Telligent can provide an Integration Software Development Kit (SDK) with source code that supports Microsoft SharePoint 2007, allowing you to extend web parts, document synchronization, and search. The SDK provides source code for a set of Microsoft SharePoint Web Parts to help you pull functionality into Microsoft SharePoint, including friend lists, group lists, activity streams, status messages, forums, blogs, etc. You can also connect media galleries with your document library.  As files change within Microsoft SharePoint, community participants see the latest version as well as the version history, enabling document management without disrupting the users’ experience. All documents are stored in Microsoft SharePoint, so when you add a document to Telligent Evolution, it automatically gets stored in Microsoft SharePoint.

Beyond document synchronization, you can integrate Microsoft SharePoint functionality (version 2007 or 2010) into the Telligent experience with iFrame widgets. You can enable a Microsoft SharePoint calendar or task list within your community.

Specifically for developers, the Telligent Evolution Developer SDK gives organizations a deeper view into the Telligent Evolution platform APIs. The developer SDK enables organizations to explore the Telligent Evolution platform and create more tailored solutions to solve specific challenges.  Hope this helps, I know this is quite a bit of information.